# Textmate : CSS bundle autocompletion

Tags: css, autocomplete, textmate

I used HTML auto-completion shortcut for the first time yesterday. I worked well. I tried to use the CSS autocompletion shortcut this morning and it did not work.

For example with :

```
#home { 
   display: ;
}
```

after typing "display:", and pressing alt+esc, I just get "--"

I am sure I am working in a CSS file. I took a look at the CSS bundle, but can't decipher the code.

Any idea ? Thanks.